# I get an error when I start with two different yml

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I encountered a problem when I was learning Eureka today.
I tried to start a SpringBoot with two different configuration files (yml), A is called application-replica1, and B is called application-replica2. There are only these two files, and there is no separate application. Below is a screenshot of the two files
[image]
[image]
I want to build an Eureka cluster, but when I start it with the first configuration file, my "server.port" function does not work. I want to set port 18081 to no effect, but port 8080 is enabled。
I tried: 1. Create a new application, and then specify the profile to start (application.profiles.,active:application-replica1), but it still doesn't work.
2.Edit Configuration, also does not work

Comment: What I wrote for the first time was: Spring.profiles.active=replica1, which also does not work

Answer (score -1):

I went out and smoked a cigarette, and it was resolved when I came back. Below is my configuration。
1 Modify the attributes of replica1 and replica2, register-with-eureka and fetch-registry are changed to true.
2. Added VM options in Edit Configuration
3. Set spring.profiles.active: replica1/replica2
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]